# slf4j simplelogger.properties not being picked up in executable jar

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, executable-jar

I am using slf4j and my simplelogger.properties is not being picked up, but if I do a simple getResourceAsStream("simplelogger.properties") call in my main method, I can indeed see the properties.  If I do /simplelogger.properties, that does NOT work.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question. Is the file in the root of your jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your resource in jar. You can do that by using [resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).

You have add the file in the root of your jar.

Comment: That doesn't seem to address my question.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. Is the file in the root of your jar file ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the root of the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `simplelogger.properties` in the classpath or alternately, you can package it in the base of your project jar packaging.